# Xampp is not open into Browser but all the thing installed successfully

Tags: mysql, database, xampp

Firstly I text the command on my terminal like sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
[sudo] password for tayef: 
Starting XAMPP for Linux 7.2.34-0...
XAMPP: Starting Apache...ok.
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...ok.
XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD...ok.
```

Secondly I text like sudo /opt/lampp/manager-linux-x64.run

```
sudo /opt/lampp/manager-linux-x64.run
```

After doing that of above xampp GUI comes like..please, click picture link below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABVHw.png)

then

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8nBx.png)

After click on Xampp home panel on Go To Application it shows like the following

```
Running Firefox as root in a regular user's session is not supported.  ($XAUTHORITY is /home/tayef/.Xauthority which is owned by tayef.)
[11635:11635:1106/191936.161137:ERROR:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(90)] Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported. See https://crbug.com/638180.
Running Firefox as root in a regular user's session is not supported.  ($XAUTHORITY is /home/tayef/.Xauthority which is owned by tayef.)
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 869: iceweasel: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 869: seamonkey: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 869: mozilla: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 869: epiphany: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 869: konqueror: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 869: chromium: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 869: chromium-browser: not found
[11665:11665:1106/191936.206660:ERROR:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(90)] Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported. See https://crbug.com/638180.
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 869: www-browser: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 869: links2: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 869: elinks: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 869: links: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 869: lynx: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 869: w3m: not found
xdg-open: no method available for opening 'http://localhost:80'
```

Comment: have you tried to search for your error: _Running Firefox as root in a regular user's session is not supported._ it is not a xampp issue. The issue is that you are trying to run xampp as root (using sudo) and xampp is triggering the browser to run using root again. If you open manually a browser and go to http://localhost:80 you should see the home page

Comment: Oh, I have search to resolve this issue but no perfect solution  being matched.If you have any solution please provide me...

Comment: Read my previous comment carefully and you will see. I have provided you the explanation and a workaround

Answer (score 1):

1. Run this command in your terminal and change `$EDITOR` with your editor

   `$EDITOR $(which google-chrome)`
2. Add -`-user-data-dirno` at the end of the file, my end looks like this

exec -a "$0" "$HERE/chrome"  "$PROFILE_DIRECTORY_FLAG" \   "$@"

3. Save and close editor
4. Use `sudo /opt/lampp/manager-linux-x64.run`
5. Go to -> manage services -> 'start all'
   you should get this result at 'application log'

   `Starting all servers... Starting MySQL Database... /opt/lampp/mysql/scripts/ctl.sh : mysql  started at port 3306 Starting Apache Web Server... /opt/lampp/apache2/scripts/ctl.sh : httpd started Starting ProFTPD... Checking syntax of configuration file /opt/lampp/proftpd/scripts/ctl.sh : proftpd started`
6. Open `http://localhost:80/phpmyadmin/` in your browser

Comment: looks like a bug related to firefox. Just changing the default editor to Google Chrome worked for me.

Comment: Yes, Firefox doesn't let you run as root, Google Chrome on the other hand does, but sometimes it requires the comment --no-sandbox in terminal